# Rails mime_types register or register_alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, parameters

Inside initialize/mime_types, If I set

```
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :mobile
```

Then when I tried to access data from a json post request, I just receive empty params

```
puts params
=> {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"users"}
```

When I switch to use register_alias

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :mobile
```

Now I can access the request data inside the params hash

```
puts params
=> {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"users", "user"=>{"email"=>"email"}}
```

Could anybody help me to understand this ?

Comment: Probably becasue json is already a mime registered in Rails?

Comment: You're right Michael , but I just don't understand why it could affect the params hash, as I Google this , I only see that register a new mime_type only affect the respond_to method.

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think that problem is caused by you redefining existing type. Try using `register_alias` only, that should work.

Comment: I did some more research and see that Rails use the registered JSON mime type to parse the request body to the params hash , it explains why when override exiting JSON mime-type, the params hash is empty.